# Proof that CRF models and logistic models are convex functions

Tags: logistic, optimization

Where can I find a good proof that CRF based models and logistic regression based models are convex? Is there a general trick to test/prove that a model or objective function is convex?

Answer (score 7):

One trick is to rewrite objective functions in terms of functions which are known to be convex.

Objective function of ML trained log-linear model is a sum of negative log-likelihoods, so it's sufficient to show that negative log-likelihood for each datapoint is convex.

Considering datapoint fixed, we can write its negative log-likelihood term as

$$-\langle \theta,\phi(y)\rangle+\log \sum_y \exp(\langle \theta,\phi(y)\rangle)$$

First term is linear so it's sufficient to show that second term, known as the log-normalizer, is convex.

Write it as $f(\mathbf{g}(\mathbf{\theta}))$ where $f(\mathbf{y})=\log \sum_y \exp y$ and $g_y(\theta)=\langle \mathbf{\theta},\phi(y)\rangle$. Here $g$ is a linear function, and $f$ is a known convex function called log-sum-exp. See page 72 of Boyd's Convex Optimization [book](http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/). Composition of a convex function and a linear function is convex, see section 3.2.2

Another approach is to use the fact that log-normalizer is the cumulant generating function. For instance see example 3.41 in Boyd's book, or Proposition 3.1 in Wainwright's "Graphical models, exponential families, and variational inference" [manuscript](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/Papers/WaiJor08_FTML.pdf). This means that second derivative is the covariance matrix of sufficient statistic $\phi$ which by definition is positive semi-definite, which means that Hessian of the log-normalizer is positive semi-definite. Positive semi-definite Hessian guarantees the function is convex, see section 3.1.4 of Boyd's book.

Technically, the log-normalizer is not the traditional cumulant generating function. CGF is $g(\phi)=\log(Z(\theta+\phi))-\log(Z(\theta))$. However, derivative of log-normalizer evaluated at $\theta$ is the same as the derivative of the CGF evaluated at $\mathbf{0}$, so it produces cumulants just like CGF.

I couldn't find full proof of equivalence, usually people omit it because it's just several steps of uninspiring algebra. A very terse derivation for continuous output space is on page 5 of Xinhua Zhang's "Graphical Models" [thesis](http://dspace.anu.edu.au/bitstream/1885/49340/1/01front.pdf). I believe a saw full derivation in Lawrence D. Brown's "Fundamentals of statistical exponential families"

Answer (score 2):

First, convexity is not only a feature of a function, but rather, a function *and* the domain over which it is defined.

To address your question more directly, another trick (rather another formulation) is to compute the Hessian matrix of your likelihood function. A per [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) *a continuous, twice differentiable function of several variables is convex on a convex set if and only if its Hessian matrix is positive semidefinite on the interior of the convex set*.

Since the Hessian is real symmetric, it is sufficient to have diagonal [dominance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix), for it to be PSD (this is obvious to show for the logistic model).